# MySQL JOIN rows if existing else fill with NULL

Tags: mysql, join, null, rows

I have two tables of peoples names and properties. Some have no entries yet and I would like to create a full list of all people and their properties (if available) else have them listed with property "NULL". That's my simplicified example:

names

```
id     name
-------------
1      Jon
2      Peter
3      Sam
4      Bruce
...
```

properties

```
names_id    property
--------------------
1           foo
3           bar
...
```

desired result:

```
id     name     property
------------------------
1      Jon      foo
2      Peter    NULL
3      Sam      bar
4      Bruce    NULL
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, using `join`:

```
  select A.id, A.name, B.property
    from table1 A
    left outer join table2  B on A.id=B.names_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use left join in this case

```
select A.id,A.name,B.property
from names A
left join properties B
on A.id=B.names_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select A.id, A.name, B.property 
from names A
left join properties B
on A.id=B.names_id ;
WHERE  A.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Care to explain why this is the answer the OP is looking for?